# java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date

Tags: java, html, mysql, sql, jsp

Se me ha presentado un problema a la hora de retornar un valor de la BD `mysql` `null` en formato `'0000-00-00'`

**El error que se presenta es:**

> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' >can not be represented as java.sql.Date
>   root cause
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as >java.sql.Date

Mi código de retorno es un  `.getDate();`

Aun así me genera error ... me podrían orientar que hice mal ?

```
//          <!--MOSTRAR LA CONSULTA  DE  BD-->
ResultSet lista = (ResultSet)request.getAttribute( "lista" );
if(lista != null){
    if( lista.first())
    {
        lista.beforeFirst();
            out.println("<form method='post' action=''>"
            + "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>"
            + "<table border ='2px' align='center' name='tableedit'>"
            + "<caption align='center'> OFICINAS EN BD </caption>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<th>ID</th>"
            + "<th>APELLIDO</th>"
            + "<th>NOMBRE</th>"        
            + "<th>CORREO</th>" 
            + "<th>CIUDAD</th>"
            + "<th>FECHA NACIMIENTO</th>"
            + "<th>SEXO</th>"
            + "<th>DIRECCION</th>"
            + "<th>TELEFONO</th>"
            + "<th>TIPO</th>"      
            + "<th>EDITAR</th>"
            + "<th>ELIMINAR</th>"
            + "</tr>");

      while( lista.next( ) ){

          //Modificamos el ID de la ciudad por el nombre para la vista
          String ciudad = lista.getString( 3 );                                                                                  
          String nc = "";

          if(!ciudad.equals("")){
          int c = Integer.parseInt(ciudad);   
          ResultSet droplst4 = s.consultarCiudades(c);
              if (droplst4.first()){//Primera coincidencia
                    nc = droplst4.getString( 2 ); 
                  }else{
                  nc = "";   
                  }
          }

          //Modificamos el ID del tipos de usuario por el nombre para la vista
          String tipo = lista.getString( 12 );
          String nt = "";

          if (!tipo.equals("")){
          int t = Integer.parseInt(tipo);
          ResultSet droplst3 = s.tiposUsuarios( 1, t );
              if (droplst3.first()){//Primera coincidencia
                   nt = droplst3.getString( 2 ); 
                   }else{
                       nt = "";    
                       } 
          }

          out.println("<tr>"
                  + "<td >" + lista.getString( 1 ) + "</td>" 
                  + "<td >" + lista.getString( 4 ) + "</td>" 
                  + "<td >" + lista.getString( 5 ) + "</td>" 
                  + "<td >" + lista.getString( 2 ) + "</td>"
                  + "<td >" + nc + "</td>"       
                  + "<td >" + lista.getDate( 6 ) + "</td>" 
                  + "<td >" + lista.getString( 7 ) + "</td>"
                  + "<td >" + lista.getString( 8 ) + "</td>"
                  + "<td >" + lista.getString( 9 ) + "</td>" 
                  + "<td >" + lista.getString( 12 ) + "</td>"         
                  + "<td >" + nt + "</td>"        
                  + "<td><a href='editarOficina.jsp?IdO="+ lista.getInt( 1 ) +" &nomO="+ lista.getString( 2 ) +" &IdZ="+ lista.getString( 3 ) +"&IdC="+ lista.getString( 4 ) +"'>"
                          + "<img src='IMG/editarCampo.png' width='25' height='25'></td>"
                  + "<td><a href='eliminarOficina.jsp?IdO="+ lista.getInt( 1 ) +" &nomO="+ lista.getString( 2 ) +" &IdZ="+ lista.getString( 3 ) +"&IdC="+ lista.getString( 4 ) +"'>"
                          + "<img src='IMG/eliminarCampo.png' width='25' height='25'></td>"         
                  + "</tr>"); 
      } 


      out.println("</table>");  
      out.println("</div>"); 
      out.println("</form>");
    }else
        {
            out.println("<h2> No se encontraron Registros</h2>");
        }
}
```

La excepción se presenta aquí:

```
 + "<td >" + lista.getDate( 6 ) + "</td>"
```

Como lo debo corregir ??

Como siempre GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL te permite (dependiendo la versión) guardar un valor “zero”, `'0000-00-00'` como si se tratase de una “fecha dummy”. Y, por defecto, el *driver* JDBC de MySQL arroja una excepción al encontrarse una fecha con éstas características.

Para modificar este comportamiento, cambia el valor por defecto de la propiedad `zeroDateTimeBehavior` a `convertToNull` en los parámetros de conexión a MySQL. Por ejemplo, si la agregaras en la URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://{host}:{port}/{dbname}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

De esta manera el *driver*, en lugar de arrojar una excepción, regresará `NULL` cuando se tope con una fecha así.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, pero al colocar esa propiedad en mi conexión me devuelve el mensaje: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet." La versión de mi mysql java connector es 5.1.13 ¿Alguna otra solución?

Answer (score 0):

Hay qye tener en cuenta que un `Java.util.Date` != `Java.sql.Date`. Es decir, un `java.sql.date`puede ser un `java.util.date` pero no al reves, para ello tendrias que formatear la Date que quieres enviar en la consulta